# SMTP Email: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such recipient

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I created a new email box for general support questions.  When I try to send an email through SMTP I receive the following error:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such recipient

I am able to email the box through Outlook and SMTP works when I send to other email address in the same domain.

Comment: Need more information.  What SMTP Server are you using to create the addresses?

Comment: And your company uses what exactly?

Comment: Exchange 2003. I am able to send emails out sucessfully through the SMTP server.  However when I use this specific email box I get the error mentioned above.  Also I am able to email the box through outlook.  It just will not send an email to the box through SMTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The great thing about SMTP is that it's easy to spoof the conversation.  The terrible thing about SMTP is also that it's easy to spoof the conversation.  What makes this great is that if you want to figure out what's going wrong in a SMTP connection you can just "telnet mailhost 25" and start issuing SMTP commands like:

```
HELO example.com
MAIL FROM: <me@me.com>
RCPT TO: <him@him.com>
DATA
Subject: test message
From: Me <me@me.com>
To: Him <him@him.com>

test message
.
QUIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your DNS configured properly? You need an MX record specifying which host handles incoming messages for that domain.

Btw, your post is missing some details, like which server you are using etc. That makes it hard to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you post the complete SMTP conversation (or at least what your client is sending) the answer will probably leap out at you.

Or, if you're speaking SMTP correctly, perhaps you're connecting to the wrong server.  Does your client look up the DNS MX record to find the right SMTP host?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the address is valid.  Also, make sure the **From** address is valid (that may be your problem).  Finally if those do not work, you should try setting the SMTP server explicitly.

Without a bit of a code sample, that's the best advice that I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Does your company have multiple mail servers? No such recipient might be returned if you have multiple servers and the newly created account hasn't been pushed through yet.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used Telnet to diagnose the problem (Thanks to Paul Tomblin for his post).  I found out that our SMTP server uses GroupWise (we use Exchange as our main email client).  I had to set up the address to relay to the GroupWise server as well.